# cs50 pset4 - edge detection filter not working - sobel operator

Tags: c, cs50, edge-detection, sobel

The following code i have written has the purpose of detecting the edges in a pixel using the sobel operator. However, it fails all of the tests given by check50 (tool offered by cs50). The output image is also the exact same as the input.

before you continue reading, visit [the pset's link](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/filter/more/#:%7E:text=Why%20these%20particular%20values%20for%20the%20kernel?%20In%20the%20Gx%20direction,%20for%20instance,%20we%E2%80%99re%20multiplying%20the%20pixels%20to%20the%20right%20of%20the%20target%20pixel%20by%20a%20positive%20number,%20and%20multiplying%20the%20pixels%20to%20the%20left%20of%20the%20target%20pixel%20by%20a%20negative%20number.%20When%20we%20take%20the%20sum,%20if%20the%20pixels%20on%20the%20right%20are%20a%20similar%20color%20to%20the%20pixels%20on%20the%20left,%20the%20result%20will%20be%20close%20to%200%20(the%20numbers%20cancel%20out).%20But%20if%20the%20pixels%20on%20the%20right%20are%20very%20different%20from%20the%20pixels%20on%20the%20left,%20then%20the%20resulting%20value%20will%20be%20very%20positive%20or%20very%20negative,%20indicating%20a%20change%20in%20color%20that%20likely%20is%20the%20result%20of%20a%20boundary%20between%20objects.%20And%20a%20similar%20argument%20holds%20true%20for%20calculating%20edges%20in%20the%20y%20direction.)

- **note:** *I'm supposed to form a 3x3 grid around the pixel* I want to filter so that I can iterate over each value in the GX and GY values. I've used ints `hh` and `ww` to do this.

```
       // Detect edges
        void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
        {
            int sqrtRedd;
            int sqrtGreenn;
            int sqrtBluee;
        
        //make copy of image
            RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
        
            for(int h = 0; h < height; h++)
            {
                for(int w = 0; w < width; w++)
                {
                    copy[h][w] = image[h][w];
                }
            }
        
        //loop through pixels
            for(int h = 0; h < height; h++)
            {
                for(int w = 0; w < width; w++)
                {
                    int GXred = 0;
                    int GYred = 0;
                    int GXgreen = 0;
                    int GYgreen = 0;
                    int GXblue = 0;
                    int GYblue = 0;
                    
                    for(int hh = -1; hh <= 1; hh++)
                    {
                        for(int ww = -1; ww <= 1; ww++)
                        {
                            if( h + hh >= 0 && h + hh < height && w + ww >= 0 && w + ww < width)
                            {
                                //form 3x3 grid
                            GXred += ww * copy[2 - hh * hh][2 - ww * ww].rgbtRed;
                            GYred += hh * copy[2 - hh * hh][2 - ww * ww].rgbtRed;
     
    
                       
                        GXgreen += ww * copy[2 - hh * hh][2 - ww * ww].rgbtGreen;
                        GYgreen += hh * copy[2 - hh * hh][2 - ww * ww].rgbtGreen;
                        
                        GXblue += ww * copy[2 - hh * hh][2 - ww * ww].rgbtBlue;
                        GXblue += hh * copy[2 - hh * hh][2 - ww * ww].rgbtBlue;
                        
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    int red = round(sqrt(GXred * GXred + GYred * GYred));
                    int green = round(sqrt(GXgreen * GXgreen + GYgreen * GXgreen));
                    int blue = round(sqrt(GXblue * GXblue + GYblue * GYblue));
                    
                    if(red > 225)
                    {
                        red = 225;
                    }
                    
                    else if(green > 225)
                    {
                        green = 225;
                    }
                    
                    else if(blue > 225)
                    {
                        blue = 225
                    }
                    
                    image[h][w].rgbtRed = red;
                    image[h][w].rgbtGreen = green;
                    image[h][w].rgbtBlue = blue;
                    
                }
            }
                
            return;
        }
```

RGBTRIPLE:

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

These are the error messages given by check50:

```
    :( edges correctly filters middle pixel
        expected "210 150 60\n", not "143 105 30\n"
    :( edges correctly filters pixel on edge
        expected "213 228 255\n", not "164 144 79\n"
    :( edges correctly filters pixel in corner
        expected "76 117 255\n", not "58 77 64\n"
    :( edges correctly filters 3x3 image
        expected "76 117 255\n21...", not "58 77 64\n164 ..."
    :( edges correctly filters 4x4 image
        expected "76 117 255\n21...", not "58 77 64\n164 ..."
```

As you can see, the output values are way off and not even near what they should actually be. the problem is: I don't know if these errors are caused by a) my way of trying to find the GX and GY values from the kernels or b)by the way i'm applying the sobel operator.

I've tried finding GX and GY values in other ways (didn't work) such as:

```
                         if(hh == -1)
                         {
                            GYred += copy[h - 1][w + ww].rgbtRed * -1;
                            GYgreen += copy[h - 1][w + ww].rgbtGreen * -1;
                            GYblue += copy[h - 1][w + ww].rgbtBlue * -1;
                         }
                         
                         else if( hh == 0)
                         {
                             GYred += copy[h][w + ww].rgbtRed * 0;
                             GYgreen += copy[h][w + ww].rgbtGreen * 0;
                             GYblue += copy[h][w + ww].rgbtBlue * 0;
                         }
                         
                         else if(hh == 1)
                         {
                             GYred += copy[h + 1][w + ww].rgbtRed * 1;
                             GYgreen += copy[h + 1][w + ww].rgbtGreen * 1;
                             GYblue += copy[h + 1][w + ww].rgbtBlue * 2;
                         }
                         
                         else if(hh == 2)
                         {
                             GYred += copy[h + 2][w + ww].rgbtRed * 2;
                             GYgreen += copy[h + 2][w + ww].rgbtGreen * 2;
                             GYblue += copy[h + 2][w + ww].rgbtBlue * 2;
                         }
                         
    //start setting GX values
                         if(ww == -2)
                         {
                             GXred += copy[h + hh][w - 2].rgbtRed * -2;
                             GXgreen += copy[h + hh][w - 2].rgbtGreen * -2;
                             GXblue += copy[h + hh][w - 2].rgbtBlue * -2;
                         }
                         
                         else if(ww == -1)
                         {
                             GXred += copy[h + hh][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1;
                             GXgreen += copy[h + hh][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -1;
                             GXblue += copy[h + hh][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -1;
                         }
                         
                         else if(ww == 0)
                         {
                             GXred += copy[h + hh][w].rgbtRed * 0;
                             GXgreen += copy[h + hh][w].rgbtGreen * 0;
                             GXblue += copy[h + hh][w].rgbtBlue * 0;
                         }
                         
                         else if(ww == 1)
                         {
                             GXred += copy[h + hh][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1;
                             GXgreen += copy[h + hh][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 1;
                             GXblue += copy[h + hh][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 1;
                         }
```

I've been stuck on this pset for almost a week now and so at this point I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Your calculations are probably off. Have you tried debugging? Another way is printing the values at checkpoints which gives you clue about what is going on..

Comment: I might have mentioned it already.... You do not apply the factors from the matrix anywhere. Also you second approach does not add any value. It is also very confusion. Now you have range `-1..1` but still check for `hh==2` or `ww==-2` which does not make any sense.

Comment: If you look at the factors again you might notice that they are not soleley depending on x or y offset for each set

Comment: @earik87 i did that once but for some reason the values won't print out. also, i don't think that i need to do that because i already know what my outputted values are from check50.

Comment: You did not understand. Checkpoints does not mean the final result. Print intermediate values where you know what value you expect. Then compare the printed value.

Comment: @earik87 i tried printing all of the GX and GY values of all colors but they wouldn't print out when i ran the program. (i tried putting printf both inside and outside of the loops)

Comment: @earik87  i just changed the way i formed a 3x3 grid around a pixel. would that help? (i edited the code in my question)

Comment: What is this intended to do? `GXred += ww * copy[2 - hh * hh][2 - ww * ww].rgbtRed;` Please start writing down what values are going to be used as index.

Comment: `else if(blue > 225)` Why do you think, you don't need check for blue overflow if green overflowed? And where do you get limit `225`? Should probably be `255`.

Comment: "The output image is also the exact same as the input." I can't really believe this. That might have been true for your first question. But even with all the mistakes, the image should have changed significantly.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but is it intentional that your RGB triples are actually BGR triples?

Comment: @Gerhardh yes. i didn't make that struct anyway, it was a part already done that came with the pset. and btw: i finally figured out the problems i had in my code. i'm done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite some parts that do not really make sense or are missing.

- You do not apply the sobel factors anywhere. Just taking the offset inside your 3x3 grid does not yield the correct values,
- You only limit 1 color channel in case of overflow,
- You limit to 225 instead of 255,
- You mixed `GXblue` and `GYblue`, same for `GXgreen` and `GYgreen`.

I have prepared a new version that should do the trick.
Now tested and with test data from initially failed test for 4x4 image.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef unsigned char BYTE;

typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;

// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int sqrtRedd;
    int sqrtGreenn;
    int sqrtBluee;

    //make copy of image
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for(int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for(int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            copy[h][w] = image[h][w];
        }
    }

    //loop through pixels
    for(int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for(int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            int GXred = 0;
            int GYred = 0;
            int GXgreen = 0;
            int GYgreen = 0;
            int GXblue = 0;
            int GYblue = 0;
            
            int index = 0;
            int factorsX[] = {-1,  0,  1, -2, 0, 2, -1, 0, 1};
            int factorsY[] = {-1, -2, -1,  0, 0, 0,  1, 2, 1};

            //form 3x3 grid
            for(int hh = -1; hh <= 1; hh++)
            {
                for(int ww = -1; ww <= 1; ww++)
                {
                    int x = w+ww;
                    int y = h+hh;
                    if( y >= 0 && y < height && x >= 0 && x < width)
                    {
                        GXred += factorsX[index] * copy[y][x].rgbtRed;
                        GYred += factorsY[index] * copy[y][x].rgbtRed;

                        GXgreen += factorsX[index] * copy[y][x].rgbtGreen;
                        GYgreen += factorsY[index] * copy[y][x].rgbtGreen;

                        GXblue += factorsX[index] * copy[y][x].rgbtBlue;
                        GYblue += factorsY[index] * copy[y][x].rgbtBlue;
                    }                   
                    index++;
                }
            }

            int red = round(sqrt(GXred * GXred + GYred * GYred));
            int green = round(sqrt(GXgreen * GXgreen + GYgreen * GYgreen));
            int blue = round(sqrt(GXblue * GXblue + GYblue * GYblue));

            if(red > 255)
            {
                red = 255;
            }
            if(green > 255)
            {
                green = 255;
            }
            if(blue > 255)
            {
                blue = 255;
            }

            image[h][w].rgbtRed = red;
            image[h][w].rgbtGreen = green;
            image[h][w].rgbtBlue = blue;
        }
    }

    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    RGBTRIPLE test_4x4[4][4] = {
        {{0, 10, 25}, {0, 10, 30}, {40, 60, 80}, {50, 60, 80}},
        {{20, 30, 90}, {30, 40, 100}, {80, 70, 90}, {80, 80, 90}},
        {{20, 20, 40}, {30, 10, 30}, {50, 40, 10}, {50, 40, 100}},
        {{50, 20, 40}, {50, 20, 40}, {50, 40, 80}, {50, 40, 80}},
    };

    edges(4, 4, test_4x4);
    for(int h = 0; h < 4; h++)
    {
        for(int w = 0; w < 4; w++)
        {
            printf("%d %d %d\n", test_4x4[h][w].rgbtBlue, test_4x4[h][w].rgbtGreen, test_4x4[h][w].rgbtRed);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain the point of the integers that you added (factorsX[], factorsY[], x, h and index). because i don't want to just alter my own code without fully understanding everything in this one. thanks!

Comment: As I have mentioned the Sobel factors multiple times, these numbers should look familiar to you. They are the factors from the link you provided: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/filter/more/sobel.png I just use them one after the other while walking through the 3x3 grid.

Comment: so i did what you reccomended and these are the errors i got:                                         
:( edges correctly filters middle pixel
    expected "210 150 60\n", not "210 150 30\n"
:) edges correctly filters pixel on edge
:) edges correctly filters pixel in corner
:( edges correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "76 117 255\n21...", not "76 117 255\n21..."
:( edges correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "76 117 255\n21...", not "76 117 255\n21...".                                                                   do you know how i might solve this?

Comment: I had a typo introduced in an edit. One factor was wrong. And I had wrong variable name `h` instead of `y`. Did you use my snippet or did you use correct factors from your task description? As mentioned the code was not tested

Comment: Also the values you added in comment do not show the error in some cases. Can you share the link to the result?

Comment: here's the link: https://submit.cs50.io/check50/337fc4743012d3a471a348a53ce301eeab7f5720                        and also i didn't use the ints x and y, i just hardcoded h + hh and w + ww

Comment: it turns out that there was a small typo. i fixed that but now everything works except for the 4x4 images.

Comment: what's strange is that it's only the green and blue values are off, but not the red. here's the new link:  https://submit.cs50.io/check50/1648945c0e2e1658c8ee58ecde7373adf98ab45a

Comment: Please add your current version below your old code to the question. It seems that only a few pixels with capped values are affected.

Comment: As you have the full set of test data, the obvious next step is to debug your application with this test case.

Comment: Not sure which typo you found. I found one in your calculation of `green`. Apart from that my code works fine. You must haveintroduced another error during copying my code. I have udpated with test case for 4x4 image